# Memory usage, failed to get convolution algorithm. this is probably because cudnn failed to initialize, TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH' True fix the issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, conv-neural-network, conda

When I am trying to fit a simple CNN model with keras using tensorflow 2.1.0, I am struggling with memory usage problems on my GPU.

First of, here are the libraries I have installed using condas:

```
tensorflow 2.1.0
cudatoolkit 10.1.243
cudnn 7.6.5
```

and here is the result of nvidia-smi after fitting the model:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   48C    P2    57W / 250W |   7788MiB /  7979MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1554      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           267MiB |
|    0      8141      C   ...da3/envs/tensorflow_gpu_test/bin/python  7443MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the model I am trying to fit:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 15, 15, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 13, 13, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                65600     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 122,570
Trainable params: 122,570
Non-trainable params: 0
```

When I am trying to fit this model, I am getting the following error:

```
CUDNN ERROR: Failed to get convolution algorithm
```

I read various posts about this error and realized that it might be due to memory errors (for what I understand, tensorflow is filling GPU memory to quickly for cudnn to initialize correctly ).
So I finally reach a solution using:

```
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
```

at the top of the script.

So, my question is simple: is there any way to handle these memory problems on my GPU without using this workaround?

Moreover, to keep things as neat as possible, I would like to **use exclusively conda** package manager to handle cuda, tensorflow and cudnn dependencies (in order to avoid mixing between pip and conda).

Thank you in advance for any tips you might provide and do not hesitate to ask should you need any further information.

EDIT: Here is a post which might help others using RTX cards with tensorflow:

[medium, RTX cards, memory usage](https://medium.com/@JeansPantRushi/fix-for-tensorflow-v2-failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-b367a088b56e)

Comment: Does no one could tell me what the deal is with RTX cards and memory management in tensorflow (see the medium link I have posted in my answer)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to solve your problem. I have built and trained many much larger models than the one you have  using the GPU without this problem occurring without having to use the work around you use. However I do get the problem if I have too many instances of python running. If I kill some of the running instances the problem goes away. None of the other instances are using the GPU but the problem still happens and I have not been able to figure out why. When you get this problem do you have multiple instances of python running? Try it with no other instances running and without the work around and see if the problem goes away. For the other issue I use both pip and conda to install packages. I have found that for tensorflow 2.0 it is better to use conda than pip because with conda the tool kit and Cudnn are automatically installed.

Comment: To ask your question, yes I am getting this problem while having a single python instance running.
When I am not using GPU_Allow_Growth trick, I am getting the error message even though there are no other GPU memory-consumming instance running